# How to extract image extention from a base64 string in python3

Tags: python-3.x, base64, image-formats

I get a base64 string with `data:image/png;base64,`(can be png or jpeg) in front of the string. first I want to retrieve the image type(extention, if it is png of jpeg). My code is as below.

```
import json
import base64
import boto3
import uuid
from io import StringIO

BUCKET_NAME = '972855876435testbucket1'

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    image = event['content']
    image = image[image.find(",")+1:]
    print(image)
    dec = base64.b64decode(image + "===")
    s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key='image1.png', Body=dec)
     return {
    'statusCode': 200
     }
```

I need to find a way to extract the format of the base64 image string

Comment: Do you mean simply extracting the file type from the string:`"data:image/png;base64,".split(";")[0].split("/")[1]`?

Comment: This made my day

Comment: In a good way or a you can't believe I'm that silly way!? :D